# What is the effect of launching from higher altitude on fuel burn and rocket performance?

Tags: launch, rockets, performance

There are many sites around the world apart from USA, that have such great locations to launch from. Saving hundreds of thousands of dollars in fuel costs.
Can someone assist me with a model that proves the effect of a geographical location such as higher field elevation above sea level? Or point me in the right direction

Comment: You also have to consider range safety and logistics - we launch next to ocean or desert so that any falling bits (expendable first stages, fairings, etc.) don't land on anyone or anything important.  It's also easier to barge large rocket stages over water than to transport them over land (the F9 is right at the limit of what is road-transportable).  Any savings from launching at higher altitude would be minimal, and would not offset the higher logistics cost.

Comment: Obligatory: orbit is fast, not high. https://what-if.xkcd.com/58/

Comment: Also: fuel is the cheapest part of a rocket.